# Why I can not use django language tag with GAE?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-1.5

I would like to support django translation on my page, so I've done the following setup:

**app.yaml**:

```
...
- name: django
  version: "1.5"
```

**conf/settings.py**:

```
USE_I18N = True

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
)
```

**template.html**:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% language 'ru' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 ...
 {% trans "This is the title." %} 
  ...
</html>
{% endlanguage %}
```

But I get `TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'language'` error. What is wrong here? [`language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates) is supported by Django 1.5. Btw, `trans` tag works fine.

Comment: What django version are you using? 1.5?..

Comment: @Sayse, it should be 1.5 in accordance with app.yaml setup.